# Showing a subgroup is $p$ complement

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a Hall $p'$ subgroup of a group $G$.

Then how can I show that $H$ is a $p$-complement of $G$?

A group $G$ is said to be $p'$ group if for any element $x$ in $G$, none of the factors of order of $x$ is $p$.

If $p$ is a prime and $G$ is a finite group of order $ap^{n}$ where $a$ is a $p'$ number(i.e none of its prime factors is p) then a $p$-complement of $G$ is a subgroup of order $a$.

Comment: What is your definition of a Hall $p'$-subgroup of $G$? (You seem to have defined everything else, but not that!)

Comment: It is a Hall subgroup and a $p'$-group.

Comment: OK, what is your definition of a Hall subgroup?

Comment: H is a hall subgroup of $G$ means that order of $H$ and its index in $G$ is relatively prime.

Comment: In that case it's not true. A subgroup of order $2$ is a group of order $30$ in a Hall $3'$-subgroup, but it is not a $3$-complement. (In fact your definitions are wrong. Such a subgroup is not usually called a Hall $3'$-subgroup.)